# matplotlib discrete data versus continuous function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, dataset

I need to plot a ratio between a function introduced thorough a discrete data set, imported from a text file, for example:

`x,y,z=np.loadtxt('example.txt',usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True)`,

and a continuous function defined using the np.arange command, for example:

`w=np.arange(0,0.5,0.01)`

`exfunct=w**4`.

Clearly, solutions as

`plt.plot(w,1-(x/w),'k--',color='blue',lw=2)` as well

`plt.plot(y,1-(x/w),'k--',color='blue',lw=2)`

do not work. Despite having looked for the answer in the site (and outside it), I can not find any solution to my problem. Should I fit the discrete data set, to obtain a continuous function, and then define it in the same interval as the "exfunct"? Any suggestion? Thank you a lot.

Comment: You could evaluate the continuous functions at the data points from the file, and plot those points and/or the ratio. Would that do?

Comment: At the end the solution has been easier than I thought. I had simply to define the continuous variable through the discrete data, as, for example:
`w=x/y` , then define the function as already said:
`exfunct=w**4` and finally plot the "continuous-discrete" function:
`plt.plot(x,x/exfunct),'k-',color='red',lw=2)`
I hope this can be useful.

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question - that way others can see that it has been answered!

Comment: You are right @jcoppens.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the solution has been easier than I thought. I had simply to define the continuous variable through the discrete data, as, for example:

`w=x/y`,

then define the function as already said:

`exfunct=w**4`

and finally plot the "continuous-discrete" function:

`plt.plot(x,x/exfunct),'k-',color='red',lw=2)`

I hope this can be useful.